# How to remove Undefined values in JAVASCRIPT from excel values (when it's blank, use blank rather than undefined)?

Tags: javascript, html, json, excel, sheetjs

I found this code that works fine but when there is a blank value in excel, it shows undefined, while i would like it to remain blank.

Any help would be great, however I just started programming a few days ago, so details on the syntax would be great (like what to remove out of the code and what to replace).

Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
    <title>Excel to HTML Table | Javacodepoint</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.17.5/xlsx.min.js"></script>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Upload an excel file to display in HTML Table</h1>
    <!-- Input element to upload an excel file -->
    <input type="file" id="file_upload" />
    <button onclick="upload()">Upload</button>  
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- table to display the excel data -->
    <table id="display_excel_data" border="1"></table>
    <script>
     
      // Method to upload a valid excel file
      function upload() {
        var files = document.getElementById('file_upload').files;
        if(files.length==0){
          alert("Please choose any file...");
          return;
        }
        var filename = files[0].name;
        var extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".")).toUpperCase();
        if (extension == '.XLS' || extension == '.XLSX') {
            //Here calling another method to read excel file into json
            excelFileToJSON(files[0]);
        }else{
            alert("Please select a valid excel file.");
        }
      }
       
      //Method to read excel file and convert it into JSON 
      
      function excelFileToJSON(file){
          try {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
            reader.onload = function(e) {
 
                var data = e.target.result;
                var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                    type : 'binary'
                });
                var result = {};
                var firstSheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
                //reading only first sheet data
                var jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName]);
                //displaying the json result into HTML table
                displayJsonToHtmlTable(jsonData);
                }
            }catch(e){
                console.error(e);
            }
      }


      //Method to display the data in HTML Table
      function displayJsonToHtmlTable(jsonData){
        var table=document.getElementById("display_excel_data");
        if(jsonData.length>0){
            var htmlData='<tr><th>Student Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Email ID</th><th>Age</th></tr>';
            for(var i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++){
                var row=jsonData[i];
                htmlData+='<tr><td>'+row["hgyu"]+'</td><td>'+row["Address"]
                      +'</td><td>'+row["Email ID"]+'</td><td>'+row["Age"]+'</td></tr>';
            }
            table.innerHTML=htmlData;
        }else{
            table.innerHTML='There is no data in Excel';
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is when you are asking for some data that might not exist in each row. When that happens, that data is `undefined` so that's what it will convert to a string and show.  A way around this is to do `row['Age'] || ''` which which somewhat treat `row['Age']` as a boolean of sorts, if it resolves to a "falsey" value like `undefined` then it will take the other side of the or statement and return an empty string like you want.

So here is all that needs to change to do this:

```js
for(var i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++){
  var row=jsonData[i];

  var hgyu = row["hgyu"] || '';
  var address = row["Address"] || '';
  var email = row["Email ID"] || '';
  var age = row["Age"] || '';

  htmlData+='<tr><td>'+hgyu+'</td><td>'+address
            +'</td><td>'+email+'</td><td>'+age+'</td></tr>';
}
```

And here is the whole thing working below.

```js
// Method to upload a valid excel file
function upload() {
  var files = document.getElementById('file_upload').files;
  if(files.length==0){
    alert("Please choose any file...");
    return;
  }
  var filename = files[0].name;
  var extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".")).toUpperCase();
  if (extension == '.XLS' || extension == '.XLSX') {
      //Here calling another method to read excel file into json
      excelFileToJSON(files[0]);
  }else{
      alert("Please select a valid excel file.");
  }
}

//Method to read excel file and convert it into JSON 

function excelFileToJSON(file){
    try {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
      reader.onload = function(e) {

          var data = e.target.result;
          var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
              type : 'binary'
          });
          var result = {};
          var firstSheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
          //reading only first sheet data
          var jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName]);
          //displaying the json result into HTML table
          displayJsonToHtmlTable(jsonData);
          }
      }catch(e){
          console.error(e);
      }
}

//Method to display the data in HTML Table
function displayJsonToHtmlTable(jsonData){
  var table=document.getElementById("display_excel_data");
  if(jsonData.length>0){
      var htmlData='<tr><th>Student Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Email ID</th><th>Age</th></tr>';
      for(var i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++){
          var row=jsonData[i];
          var hgyu = row["hgyu"] || '';
          var address = row["Address"] || '';
          var email = row["Email ID"] || '';
          var age = row["Age"] || '';
          htmlData+='<tr><td>'+hgyu+'</td><td>'+address
                +'</td><td>'+email+'</td><td>'+age+'</td></tr>';
      }
      table.innerHTML=htmlData;
  }else{
      table.innerHTML='There is no data in Excel';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.17.5/xlsx.min.js"></script>    

<h1>Upload an excel file to display in HTML Table</h1>
<!-- Input element to upload an excel file -->
<input type="file" id="file_upload" />
<button onclick="upload()">Upload</button>  
<br>
<br>
<!-- table to display the excel data -->
<table id="display_excel_data" border="1"></table>
```

---

### EDIT

Adding on here to demonstrate how to add a new table for each excel row, as discussed in the comments on this answer.

```js
// Method to upload a valid excel file
function upload() {
  var files = document.getElementById('file_upload').files;
  if(files.length==0){
    alert("Please choose any file...");
    return;
  }
  var filename = files[0].name;
  var extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".")).toUpperCase();
  if (extension == '.XLS' || extension == '.XLSX') {
      //Here calling another method to read excel file into json
      excelFileToJSON(files[0]);
  }else{
      alert("Please select a valid excel file.");
  }
}

//Method to read excel file and convert it into JSON 

function excelFileToJSON(file){
    try {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
      reader.onload = function(e) {

          var data = e.target.result;
          var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
              type : 'binary'
          });
          var result = {};
          var firstSheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
          //reading only first sheet data
          var jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName]);
          //displaying the json result into HTML table
          displayJsonToHtmlTable(jsonData);
          }
      }catch(e){
          console.error(e);
      }
}

//Method to display the data in HTML Table
function displayJsonToHtmlTable(jsonData){
  var table=document.getElementById("display_excel_data");
  if(jsonData.length>0){
      var htmlData=''
      
      for(var i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++){
          var row=jsonData[i];
          var hgyu = row["hgyu"] || '';
          var address = row["Address"] || '';
          var email = row["Email ID"] || '';
          var age = row["Age"] || '';
          
          htmlData+='<table border="1">'
           +'<tr><th>Student Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Email ID</th><th>Age</th></tr>'
           +'<tr><td>'+hgyu+'</td>'
           +'<td>'+address+'</td>'
           +'<td>'+email+'</td>'
           +'<td>'+age+'</td>'
           +'</tr></table>';
      }
      table.innerHTML=htmlData;
  }else{
      table.innerHTML='There is no data in Excel';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.17.5/xlsx.min.js"></script>    

<h1>Upload an excel file to display in HTML Table</h1>
<!-- Input element to upload an excel file -->
<input type="file" id="file_upload" />
<button onclick="upload()">Upload</button>  
<br>
<br>
<!-- table to display the excel data -->
<div id="display_excel_data"></div>
```

Basically in the actual HTML it now just uses a `<div>` for everything to be inserted into.  In the script now the table and the table headers are moved inside of the `for` loop so that it runs each time.

Comment: Hi @FiniteLooper Is there a way from the previous code to build a table for each row in excel (rather than a TR, it is a Table?)?

For example, rather than htmlData+='<tr><td>' , it becomes htmlData+='<table><tr><td>' , but it doesn't work.

Comment: It can certainly work, but the problem I'm guessing you are having is that the current code has a `<table>` element already in the HTML and then all the `<tr>`'s are being added into it.  If you want to add a new table for each excel row you will have to move some stuff around because you cannot put a `<table>` inside another `<table>` to achieve what you want.  I will add onto my answer to show you what I mean

Comment: Hi @FiniteLooper I can not thank you enough for the help, it's working great! I am learning a lot from you. I am trying to use the same understanding to a similar situation, but I encounter a problem. I think it might have to do with some javascript inside a javascript function.. I don't know how to post the code in the comment reply, so I would just post it in a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76237221/javascript-inside-a-javafunction-not-loading-not-sure-how-to-syntax-it